# NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate : controllerDidChangeContent not working in iOS 8

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, core-data, ios8

I am tryin to use NSFetchedResultsController in a UITableView.. But for some reason the     NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate are not getting fired when I add a new entry. Here is the complete code

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

let coreDataStack = CoreDataStack()
class CDListViewController: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {


    var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController {
        if _fetchedResultsController != nil {
            return _fetchedResultsController!
        }
        let fRequest = fetchRequest()

        let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fRequest, managedObjectContext: coreDataStack.managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

        aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self
        _fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController

        var error: NSError? = nil
        if !_fetchedResultsController!.performFetch(&error) {
        }
        println(error)

        return _fetchedResultsController!
    }

    var _fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController? = nil

    func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Menu")

        // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
        fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 2

        // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "createdAt", ascending: false)

        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        return fetchRequest
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
        print(fetchedResultsController)
//        fetchedResultsController?.performFetch(nil)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let menus = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects as [Menu]
        return menus.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        let curr = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as Menu
        // Configure the cell...
        cell.textLabel?.text = curr.text
        return cell
    }



    // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true
    }



    // Override to support editing the table view.

    func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
        println("Coming in here")
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    }

    func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
    }




    // Override to support editing the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let entry = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as Menu
        coreDataStack.managedObjectContext?.deleteObject(entry)
        coreDataStack.saveContext()
    }

    func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
        switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Insert : self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
            break
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Delete : self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
            break
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Update : self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
        default:
            println("Nothing")
        }
    }

    func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeSection sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atIndex sectionIndex: Int, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {
        switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Insert : self.tableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
            break
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Delete : self.tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
            break
        default:
            println("Nothing")
        }
    }

}
```

When I add an entry to the context and save the content neither `controllerWillChangeContent` nor `controllerDidChangeContent` is being called. I made sure that the context is saved because if I restart the app I can see the recently added entry.
Can anyone find any issue with the code written above?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed you set the delegate twice. Once inside the computed property and once in the `viewDidLoad`. I think your issue may arise from the fact that you set it for `aFetchedResultsController` in the computed property first, and thus, the delegate methods are called when `aFetchedResultsController`'s delegate methods are called (which they are not). Deleting the delegation assignment (`aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self`) in your computed property should resolve this issue.

Comment: Figured it out.. I had multiple managedObject context. Creating a single managed object context solved the problem